# MongoDB and returning collections efficiently

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am very new to Mongo (this is actually day 1) and using the C# driver that is available for it. One thing that I want to know (as I am not sure how to word it in Google) is how does mongo handle executing queries when I want to grab a part of the collection.

What I mean by this is that I know that with NHibernate and EF Core, the query is first built and it will only fire when you cast it. So say like an IQueryable to IEnnumerable, .ToList(), etc.

Ex:

```
//Query is fired when I call .ToList, until that point it is just building it
context.GetLinqQuery<MyObject>().Where(x => x.a == 'blah').ToList();
```

However, with Mongo's examples it appears to me that if I want to grab a filtered result I will first need to get the collection, and then filter it down.

Ex:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<MyObject>("MyObject");
//Empty filter for ease of typing for example purposes
var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Empty;
var collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Am I missing something here, I do not think I saw any overload in the GetCollection method that will accept a filter. Does this mean that it will first load the whole collection into memory, then filter it? Or will it still be building the query and only execute it once I call either .Find or .ToList on it?

I ask this because at work we have had situations where improper positioning of .ToList() would result is seriously weak performance. Apologies if this is not the right place to ask.

References: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read_queries/

Comment: `.AsQueryable()`?

Comment: @John but that still wouldn't allow me to have a filter before hand right? Like it will still grab the collection and then filter it?

Comment: I think you are missing that `GetCollection()` returns a reference to a collection instance (i.e. `database.collection` namespace), but does not return or load any documents in the collection. Your second example works similar to the first: the query won't execute until you call `Find()`, which returns a query cursor. Adding `ToList()`will iterate the cursor to return all results in a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to your `context.GetLinqQuery<MyObject>()` would be to use `AsQueryable`:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.a == "blah").ToList();
```

The above query will be executed server side<sup>*</sup> and is equivalent to:

```
collection.Find(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq(x => x.a, "blah")).ToEnumerable().ToList();
```

<sup>*</sup> [The docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/linq/) state that:

> Only LINQ queries that can be translated to an equivalent MongoDB query are supported. If you write a LINQ query that can’t be translated you will get a runtime exception and the error message will indicate which part of the query wasn’t supported.